# SSDT has an unresolved reference to object for views but works fine for procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

This error is not the "normal error", when there is a missing database reference. I have a database reference added correctly, and it worked fine so far with stored procedures.

**The problem:**

I have a database project, let's call it **BIDK**. This database has a reference to dacpac file, build from a nother database project called **RPTDK**.

**RPTDK** has a table called **dbo.BILLINGITEM**, which I can reference from **BIDK** database project using this code:

```sql
create proc CommonDM.TestReferenceFromProc
as
select BILLINGITEM_ID,
       TIMESTAMP,
       BILLINGITEMTYPE_ENUMID,
       VATCODE_ENUMID,
       LCOMPANY_ID,
       LEASESERVICECOMPONENT_ID
from [RPTDK].[dbo].BILLINGITEM as bilitm;
```

This works fine, and I can build the project BIDK. *Shiny Happy Poeple Dancing!*

However, if I add this view, then the build fails:

```sql
create view CommonDM.TestReferenceFromView
as
select BILLINGITEM_ID,
       TIMESTAMP,
       BILLINGITEMTYPE_ENUMID,
       VATCODE_ENUMID,
       LCOMPANY_ID,
       LEASESERVICECOMPONENT_ID
from [RPTDK].[dbo].BILLINGITEM as bilitm
```

I cannot build the project **BIDK** with the view added, and I get the error message:

```
[CommonDM].[TestReferenceFromView] has an unresolved reference to object [RPTDK].[dbo].[BILLINGITEM]
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Why is it working for stored proc and not for views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing and trying different settings, I can conclude that the "correct" approach is to use the **[$(RPTDK)]** syntax, where the RPTDK is the name that of the parameter, as it is set when one adds the database reference to begin with.

```sql
select BILLINGITEM_ID,
       TIMESTAMP,
       BILLINGITEMTYPE_ENUMID,
       VATCODE_ENUMID,
       LCOMPANY_ID,
       LEASESERVICECOMPONENT_ID
from [$(RPTDK)].[dbo].BILLINGITEM as bilitm
```

It is a bit annoying, and the code is now dependent on a SQLCMD mode parameter to work, when you want to copy and paste into a SSMS window.

Thanks Alfin for the assistance.

**ps**

The reason why this is not failing in a stored proc, is that it seems to be that Visual Studio SSDT is not checking for referenced objects in a stored proc, but does it for views. I tried to remove the reference all togetger, and the stored proc code still managed to build succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had a case like this before, instead of specifying database name, try to select without specifying the database name like this

```
select BILLINGITEM_ID,
   TIMESTAMP,
   BILLINGITEMTYPE_ENUMID,
   VATCODE_ENUMID,
   LCOMPANY_ID,
   LEASESERVICECOMPONENT_ID
from [dbo].BILLINGITEM
```

or using [$DBName] for the database name like this

```
select BILLINGITEM_ID,
   TIMESTAMP,
   BILLINGITEMTYPE_ENUMID,
   VATCODE_ENUMID,
   LCOMPANY_ID,
   LEASESERVICECOMPONENT_ID
from [$RPTDK].[dbo].BILLINGITEM as bilitm
```

it worked for me

Comment: The first one without stating the name of the databse did not work. But the second allow me now to build, however, this is rather anoying still, as I can no longer copy paste parts of the code from Visual Studio over to SSMS, without constantly switching from the $ version (which is essentially a parameter i SQLCMD mode) and the actual value.                                              This is really anoying, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To be short - SSDT likes 2-part names. You can use variables for 3-4 part names, but ideally you should create either dacpac or project for each external database. Then reference them in your main project. Then for every external object you need to create synonyms and then you'll not have more problems. Moreover it will give you possibility to have different databases/instances names on different environments.

You can find an example how to organize the solution with SSDT in my [github repo](https://github.com/dkultasev/SSDTPowerTemplate). I still want to add some more stuff there, but you can see an example how to work with it for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, and I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to the correct answer above, but I wanted to supply a detail to the answer so I'm entering it as an 'answer'.

The reason stored procedures with unknown references (as opposed to views) cannot be flagged as errors by the SSDT reference checker is that stored procedures are dynamic and can affect the schema during execution.

In other words, a proc could reference TableA which does not exist when the project is deployed, but the proc could dynamically create TableA before it needs to use it.  If SSDT flagged the unknown reference as an error, you could never build the project and never deploy it.